# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [certs/dev/test.crt] cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, tomcat

My springboot war application is deployed to ec2 instance through Elastic beanstalk. I am trying to read a file from the resources folder and getting the following exception.  certs folder is inside resources folder.

Apr  8 22:42:03  web: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [certs/dev/test.crt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/var/app/current/target/test-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/certs/dev/test.crt

```
import com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.sample.sampleUtil.SampleUtil;

private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

Resource certRes = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:certs/dev/test.crt");
Resource privateRes = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:certs/dev/private.key");

String certificateFile = certRes.getFile().getPath();
String privateKeyFile = privateRes.getFile().getPath();

SampleUtil.KeyStorePasswordPair pair = SampleUtil.getKeyStorePasswordPair(certificateFile, privateKeyFile);
```

I tried to use ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream to read the file, but  SampleUtil.KeyStorePasswordPair needs a path.

Can anyone please help?

In the error, I see "jar:file", but my app is war. is that a problem?

Ann

Comment: You cannot convert a class path resource to a `java.util.File`. The latter needs to be an actual file resource on the file system. When something is inside a WAR/JAR this isn't the case so `getFile` won't work. You can only use an `InputStream` to read it or need to find a different way to convert to a `Path` or use a different way to generate your `SampleUtil.KeyStorePasswordPair`.

Comment: Also - have you checked whether the file is actually inside the war file?

Comment: Refer this link. There is an option to read classpath resource as input stream inside a jar file. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access